# Can I sell a PDF through the iBooks store?

Tags: pdf, ibooks-author

I want to sell my children's books on Apple.  They are ready because I made them all on Corel. Is there a possibility of turning them into PDF and publishing them in that format or will I have to do it all again on iBooks Author?

Answer (score 5):

Apple has a support document that addresses this very topic:  [Publish and sell books with iBooks Author](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201183)

- If you intend to put your books up for sale on the Apple Book Store, then they **must** be in the iBooks (.ibooks) or EPUB (.epub) format.  You will have to use iBooks Author for .ibooks.  For .epub you can use iBA, Pages, or various other apps.
- If you intend to have a wider distribution outside of iBooks, then they must be in a different format than iBooks like PDF or EPUB.  If you go this route, you don't need to use iBooks Author; you can use the PDFs generated in Corel. One vendor for this is gumroad - https://gumroad.com/